# How to enumerate sessions from different request using express-session?

Tags: express, session, express-session

I wanna make sure an account is only logged in by one user. So, I need to retrieve all sessions in the session storage and check if its user is the same as the one just logged in. If it is, delete that old session. But it seems like I can only enumerate session by req object. Any ideas? Thank you for all the help! (I am using psql sessionStorage)

Comment: express-session objects are indexed in the session store by their dynamically generated sessionID (stored in the session cookie), not by your userID.  To find any other session objects with that userID in them, you'd have to iterate every single session object stored in the session store and compare each one to see if it has the target userID in it.  If so, delete it from the session store.  This would all be direct manipulation of the session store outside of express-session, not something express-session supports.

Comment: @jfriend00 Okay, that is what I intended to do. But your comment made me realized that I can just do queries to my database and delete session with certain username. Thank you for the help!